# How to add a tooltip on top of bar multi-bar chart to find the difference in percentage between the bars in echarts?

Tags: bar-chart, echarts

I want to add a tootip on top of a multi-bar chart which will show the difference between two charts in percentage in the . It would look something like as shown in the image below

[Multi bar chart with difference in percentage between bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbXe1.png)

Is there any api to implement. If not how can i implement this feature by forking the echarts library?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this API already exists, you need to use [Tooltip component](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.tooltip). It can be customized for each bar if need. It makes sense to start the learn from [base concepts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#ECharts%20Basic%20Concepts%20Overview) and [tooltip docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip).